# slow down for in loop

Tags: cocoa, swift, sleep, for-in-loop

I have a function that loops through a list of items by sending them to a server and grabbing the response. The problem I'm having is the loop is going faster than the server can handle. I need to figure out a way to slow the loop down without freezing the application. Is there a way to delay the loop from moving to the next item for a brief moment? In other languages, I'd use something like sleep(interval).

Comment: This makes no sense.  Why would you ever want to slow a server process down?

Comment: I'm not slowing down the server process. I'm slowing down the time between each request that is being sent to the server. Currently as is, the loop sends all of the requests(300+) as fast as it can which is resulting in timeout errors.

Answer (score 1):

Don't slow the process down. Add the network calls to an operation queue with a limited number of concurrent operations. You may need to rewrite your network code as an NSOperation subclass but that's fairly straightforward. You can see some examples in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift).

There is a built-in limit to the number of simultaneous network connections that can be made anyway, but it sounds like your server's limit is lower than that, or that you're saturating the network connections and your later calls are timing out before they've been able to start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a sleep interval it sounds like you want a completion block that calls the same code again until the list is empty. So once it finishes the request, it goes onto the next one.

Also I don't think you should be trying to sleep since it will hold the main thread which results in a poor user experience.

Comment: It sounds like this would be a decent method of achieving my end goal. I'm just not sure how to use a completion block. All of the examples I found were animation based. Do you have an example that deals with http functionality? I'm using a post method to send the data to the server.

Comment: @BooMSticK Check out AFNetworking. If you are not in a position to switch to another library you can check out that code to implement blocks.